# Is phpMyAdmin WCAG 2.0 compliant?

Tags: phpmyadmin, wcag2.0

I have a requirement that all my internet and intranet web sites be WCAG 2.0 level A and AA compliant by the end of 2015.  Right now, I just need to identify what is/isn't compliant and how much effort is it to make it compliant.

If phpMyAdmin is compliant, what version do I need to have to be compliant?

If phpMyAdmin isn't compliant, are any of the devs working in that direction?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming or development. Perhaps you should try [User Experience Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/). Also see [How to Meet WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/) on the W3C site.

Comment: @jww I posted the question here as the phpmyadmin website says "Effective September 1st, 2013, support for questions directly related to phpMyAdmin has moved to stackoverflow. All prior support mechanisms have been phased out. " [link](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/support.php)

Comment: Haha! I don't think the PHPAdmin folks dictate Stack Overflow policy. Maybe they should have said something like "Ask your question on a site in the Stack Exchange network". In your case, the UX SE is probably most appropriate. Since it has nothing to do with programming or development, its definitely not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**References**
http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/
RELEASE_4_4_1-1208-g286b31c

You can quickly test a piece of software by looking at it against the WCAG checklist. http://webaim.org/standards/wcag/checklist

Just a quick test using the demo I would fail it at WCAG2.0 LevelA. Below are a couple reasons I feel it fails after about a 15 minute review. It looks like there are enough issues with phpmyadmin that I wouldn't tackle trying to make it complaint. You would be better off replacing it with some home grown tool that provides the users just enough to get done what they need to get done that is WCAG compliant or simply train your your folks how to use mysql CLI.

1. 2.1.1 (Level A) - All page functionality is available using the keyboard, unless the functionality cannot be accomplished in any known way using a keyboard (e.g., free hand drawing).

   - Really doesn't seem to function too well or at all with keyboard. I'm not great with keyboard only controls but I don't seems to be able to get anywhere.
2. 2.1.2 No Keyboard Trap (Level A) - Keyboard focus is never locked or trapped at one particular page element. The user can navigate to and from all navigable page elements using only a keyboard.

   - Seems like keyboard is trapped in select a database/table frame on the left.
3. 2.4.4 Link Purpose (In Context) (Level A) - The purpose of each link (or form image button or image map hotspot) can be determined from the link text alone, or from the link text and its context (e.g., surrounding paragraph, list item, table cell, or table headers).
   Links (or form image buttons) with the same text that go to different locations are readily distinguishable.

   - Table links in the left frame are all title are  "Structure" so these links won't be readily distinguishable.
   - Further the EDIT, COPY, DELETE links on table row data doesn't distinguish which row it will impact. This alone would fail the whole app at Level A.

.
4. 3.3.1 (Level A) Error Identification - errors are presented in an efficient, intuitive, and accessible manner. The error is clearly identified, quick access to the problematic element is provided, and user is allowed to easily fix the error and resubmit the form.

- Go to Database and create a new table without providing a name. The error is a tool tip popup which you loose by changing focus. This will make it very difficult for  a visually impaired user to detect the validation error.

Comment: I created a new proposal in Area51 http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87184/web-accessibility I feel your question wouldn't be right for the UX SE either. This question leads into a policy discuss of what does and does not need to be compliant.

Comment: My requirement is mandated by the government http://webguide.gov.au/accessibility-usability/accessibility.  It's going to be easier to switch to another mysql client than to either make phpmyadmin compliant or to go through the exemption process.